# Proof of Co-H map the map $f:\Sigma SU(4)\rightarrow \Sigma^2 \mathbb{CP^3}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology

How to show the map $f:\Sigma SU(4)\rightarrow \Sigma^2 \mathbb{CP^3}$ is Co-H-map?

Comment: Which map are you talking about?

Comment: Let $a: \Sigma \mathbb{CP^3}\rightarrow SU(4)$ is the inclusion. The map $f$ is left homotopy inverse of $\Sigma a$.

Comment: Is $f$ the suspension of a map $SU(4) \to \Sigma \mathbb {CP}^3$? (Also, personally, I'm still not sure exactly what the map $a$ is, or why it has a left inverse, or which left inverse you're choosing, though perhaps that's just because I'm not that familiar with "standard" cell structures on these spaces.)